# How to add value to a number using range inputs for a cost calculator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a cost calculator. Basically I have values within checkbox inputs and as they are checked, they are added together using jQuery.

```
$('.option').click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.option:checked').each(function(){
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    }); 
    $('.estimate').html('$' + total);
}); 

<input class="option" type="checkbox" value="1000"  />
<input class="option" type="checkbox" value="200"  />
<input class="option" type="checkbox" value="750"  />
```

So in the above example, the total would be 1950.  That part of the function works fine, but I want to add two range sliders in to the equation.

```
<input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="3">
<input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="3">
```

Each of the 4 positions of the slider would increase the value added to the overall total.  How could I add the range slider positions in to the above function?

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2MLKc/

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Yes, I added it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the input's change event:

http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/2MLKc/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var total;

    var addToTotal = function(){
        total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    };

    var compute = function() {
        total = 0;
        $('.option:checked,.range').each(addToTotal);
        $('.estimate').text('$' + total);    
    };

    $('.option, .range').change(compute);
});
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Is there any way to set specific values on the various range points?

Comment: Yes you can change the min max ranges with `$('.range').attr({min:100,max:200})`

Comment: You can change the ranges, but can you set each one to be a specific value. ie, the first is 250, the second is 750? They wouldn't be incremental.

Comment: Not sure if you can set specific hard-coded values, but you can change the increment with the "step" attribute. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/2MLKc/5/

Comment: If you want the user to choose a number from a list of specific values, maybe radio buttons or a select element would fit better.

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple change to what you have to make it work.

```
$('input').change(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.option:checked').each(function(){
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
  }); 
  $('.range').each(function(){
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $('.estimate').html('$' + total);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6DbFH/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do something quite similar like with the checkbox. With jQuery you can get the value of a slider input with $(selector).val().

But I recommend to abstract the calculation on another function and call it from the $('.option').click(function()... and the $('.range').change(function()...